# FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. * Where: Build file 'F:\Developed App\untitled1\android\build.gradle' line: 24

Tags: firebase, flutter, build, field, sha1

F:\Developed App\untitled1\android>gradlew signingReport

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'F:\Developed App\untitled1\android\build.gradle' line: 24
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.

> A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not open proj generic class cache for build file 'F:\Developed App\untitled1\android\app\build.gradle' (C:\Users\Raihan.gradle\caches\6.7\scripts\b8f
> tacjwav9hf6p50aw09t36z).
> > BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '*BuildScript*' Unsupported class file major version 60

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s

F:\Developed App\untitled1\android>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Go to `C:\Users\Raihan.gradle\caches\` and try to remove everything inside this `caches` folder.
2. Then remove `untitled1/.gradle/caches/`
3. If you're using an Android Studio, go to File -> Invalidate caches and restart

Hopefully, your problem will be solved